# Terraform plan failing with access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

When i try to run the terraform plan i getting an error

```
Error loading state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
        status code: 403, request id: ******, host id: *****=
```

Terraform v0.9.11

I have two aws accounts new and old, i thought it was using my old credentials so i changed my ~/.aws/credentials file

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <KEY>
aws_secret_access_key = <SECRET>

[old]
aws_access_key_id = <KEY>
aws_secret_access_key = <SECRET>
```

still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried putting your AWS creds in the terraform file?

Comment: no i tired using ~/.aws/credentials

Comment: when i do aws sts get-caller-identity return my old account id , how can i set it to new account id?

Comment: Try running 'aws configure' in your terminal. This should ask you some questions, and set the AWS vars. Also, you may have them set in your bash profile.

Comment: or in system enviroinment varialbes, unset them `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` , `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`